# Django Rest Framework ModelSerializer custom serializer field to_internal_value doesn't save to object

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-rest-framework

I have model and serializer, there is ArrayField(postgres) in that model.

Now I wanted to create a serializer field that will receive list `[1,2]` and save it to object, but for a list and detail in serializer to show a list of JSON objects.

Model:

```py
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True, blank=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(
        'Full name', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    roles = ArrayField(
        models.PositiveSmallIntegerField(),
        default=list,
        blank=True
    )
```

Serializer:

```py
class ArraySerializerField(ListField):

    def __init__(self, queryset, serializer_class):
        super(ArraySerializerField, self).__init__()
        self.queryset = queryset
        self.serializer_class = serializer_class

    def to_representation(self, value):
        if value:
            qs = self.queryset.filter(pk__in=value)
            return self.serializer_class(qs, many=True).data

        return []

    def to_internal_value(self, value):
        super(ArraySerializerField, self).to_internal_value(value)
        print(value)  # [1, 2]
        return value


class UserSerializer(SerializerExtensionsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    roles = ArraySerializerField(queryset=Role.objects.all(), serializer_class=RoleSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'full_name', 'roles')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data) 
        # {'email': 'test@test.com', 'full_name': 'Test', 'roles': []}
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

        return user
```

Now when I do list or detail request, everything is ok, I get a list of roles as JSON.

But when I try to POST data and send with this data:

```
{
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "full_name": "Test",
  "roles": [1, 2]
}
```

`validated_data` in `create` method shows roles always as `[]` and object is saved without roles, but print from `to_internal_value` shows `[1, 2]`.

What am I doing wrong? It should save sent data because `to_internal_value` works fine.

**EDIT:**

GET and LIST response gives me right format:

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "email": "test@test.com",
  "full_name": "Test",
  "roles": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "name": "Role 1"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "name": "Role 2"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
class UserSerializer(SerializerExtensionsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    roles = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField(), allow_empty=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'full_name', 'roles')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # check validated_data here
        ...
```

### Note

I'm not sure about the nature of **`SerializerExtensionsMixin`** class here. Also I'm not sure the intention behind the `queryset` and `serializer_class` arguments of your custom **`ListField`**

---

### Django Shell Output

```
In [7]: from rest_framework import serializers                                                                                                                                                                     

In [8]: class UserSerializer(serializers.Serializer):  # Created a simple serializer without model
   ...:     roles = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField(), allow_empty=True, required=False) 
   ...:     email = serializers.EmailField() 
   ...:     full_name = serializers.CharField() 
   ...:                                                                                                                                                                                                            

In [9]: data = { # your data
   ...:   "email": "test@test.com", 
   ...:   "full_name": "Test", 
   ...:   "roles": [1, 2] 
   ...: }                                                                                                                                                                                                          

In [10]: u = UserSerializer(data=data)                                                                                                                                                                             

In [11]: u.is_valid()                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[11]: True

In [12]: u.data  # got valid data                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[12]: {'roles': [1, 2], 'email': 'test@test.com', 'full_name': 'Test'}

In [13]: data["roles"] = [] # change data to accept empty list                                                                                                                                                                                       

In [14]: u = UserSerializer(data=data)                                                                                                                                                                             

In [15]: u.is_valid()                                                                                                                                                                                              
Out[15]: True

In [16]: u.data  # got validated data with empty list                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[16]: {'roles': [], 'email': 'test@test.com', 'full_name': 'Test'} 

In [17]: data["roles"] = ["foo","bar"]   #added string to the list                                                                                                                                                                          

In [18]: u = UserSerializer(data=data)                                                                                                                                                                             

In [19]: u.is_valid()  # validation failed                                                                                                                                                                                            
Out[19]: False

In [20]: u.errors                                                                                                                                                                                                  
Out[20]: {'roles': {0: [ErrorDetail(string='A valid integer is required.', code='invalid')], 1: [ErrorDetail(string='A valid integer is required.', code='invalid')]}}
```

---

## UPDATE-1

Create a **`RoleSerializer`** and use it in the **`UserSerializer`**

```
class RoleSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Role
        fields = ('id', 'name')


class UserSerializer(SerializerExtensionsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    roles = serializers.ListField(child=serializers.IntegerField(), allow_empty=True, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'full_name', 'roles')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # check validated_data here
        ...

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        rep = super().to_representation(instance)
        rep['roles'] = RoleSerializer(Role.objects.filter(id__in=rep['roles']), many=True).data
        return rep
```

---

## UPDATE-2

Using a custom array field

```
class ArrayField(serializers.ListField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.queryset = kwargs.pop('queryset', None)
        self.serializer_class = kwargs.pop('serializer_class', None)
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def to_representation(self, data):
        qs = self.queryset.filter(id__in=data)
        serializer = self.serializer_class(qs,many=True)
        return serializer.data

class UserSerializer(SerializerExtensionsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    roles = ArrayField(queryset=Role.objects.all(), serializer_class=RoleSerializer)

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'full_name', 'roles')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        # check validated_data here
        ...
```

Comment: This will help me receive `[1,2]` and save it, but as you see, on `u.data`(line 12) you get `[1,2]` as roles, but I want to get list of objects for example `[{"id":1, "name":'Role 1"},{"id":2, "name":'Role 2"}]` because of that i am using `queryset` and `serializer_class` in my custom field. So this doesn't work as I expect.

Comment: In which type you need data in the create method?

Comment: Attar of integers. I get that in internal value but in validated_data its empty.

Comment: In my solution, the saving process is ok... and you need to change the response...right?

Comment: Yes, and in my solution response is ok but saving is not.

Comment: Any way that this can be used in my custom field? And do you know why it is not working? Its more clean solution to have this custom serializer field and use on all places where it needs to be used for array field.

Comment: I'll look into it. Anyway, did my changes result in expected output?

Comment: It works, thank you. `to_internal_value` is removed and it works, it's weird. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Try switching to [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield). Though you'll need to change your user model to use an actual relation. Which is generally a good idea because it'll help enforce data integrity with your project.

```
class User(models.Model):
    email = models.EmailField('Email', unique=True, blank=False)
    full_name = models.CharField(
        'Full name', max_length=150, blank=True, null=True)
    roles = models.ManyToManyField(Role, blank=True)

class UserSerializer(SerializerExtensionsMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    roles = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(
        many=True,
        queryset=Role.objects.all(),
    )

    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('id', 'email', 'full_name', 'roles')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        print(validated_data) 
        # {'email': 'test@test.com', 'full_name': 'Test', 'roles': []}
        user = super(UserSerializer, self).create(validated_data)

        return user
```

Comment: I know that, but I don’t want to use one more database table for it, thats the reason that I use ArrayField. I need this solution on ArrayField.

Comment: You really should. It's a much better solution all around.